# Is the composition of two bundle projections necessarily a bundle projection?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

That is, if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow Z$ are bundle projections, is $g \circ f: X \rightarrow Z$ a bundle projection? Assume $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are manifolds.

Here is what I know. The answer is affirmative when (1) $f$ is a covering map and $g$ is bundle projection; (2) $f$ is a bundle projection and $g$ is a covering map of finite degree.
What can we say about the most general situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. It follows directly from the definition.

Comment: To Charlie: Just to make sure we have the same definition in mind, a bundle projection requires a cover of the base space by locally trivial neighborhoods and a typical fiber. Using this definition, it is not obvious to me why the composition should be a bundle projection. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Charlie: it doesn't follow from the definition nor from anything else because it is false; see my answer.

Comment: I stand corrected. 

Comment: @Michael: I am afraid I find  your assertion (1) suspicious, since it is not true even if *both* $f$ and $g$ are covering spaces. Could you please clarify what you mean by supplying an argument or a reference?

Comment: What about when the spaces involved are locally contractible?

Comment: @ David: That's a question I am also interested in knowing the answer to.

Comment: @ Georges: Sorry I was assuming the spaces involved are manifolds. I've had it edited. Please also see my comment to your answer.

Comment: In general when you edit a question it's good to make it clear what the edit was so that if people don't change their answers, then readers can still figure out what question the answers address.

Answer (score 11):

No, the composition of two bundle projections needn't be a bundle projection.
 It is already not true that the composition of two covering maps is a covering map.
You can find a counterexample in Spanier's classic [*Algebraic Topology*](http://books.google.fr/books?id=h-wc3TnZMCcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=spanier+algebraic+topology&hl=fr&ei=_15lTp61C8Pj4QTU0vDHCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false), Chapter 2, §2, Example 8, page 69.

Another counterexample, based (!) on the notorious Hawaiian ring space is given by Jerzac's very  nice,detailed paper [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Jerzak.pdf).

However, on the positive side, the composition   $g\circ f :X\to Z$   of the covering maps $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$
*is* a covering map in each of the following two cases:
a) The covering $g$ is finite (= has finite fibers)
b)  The space  $Z$ has a universal covering  (for connected $Z$, this means that  $Z$ is  locally pathwise connected and semi-locally simply connected). For example, CW-complexes  have a universal covering space, since they are even locally contractible.

Comment: Georges -- that's a good example. However, I believe for reasonably nice spaces the statement should be true. I'm not sure what exactly the "reasonably nice" condition is, but I guess it would suffice to require that the 1-point compactifications of all spaces should be finite CW-complexes.

Comment: Thanks to Georges' for your answer. Would the answer be positive if we assume $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are manifolds, which is really what I meant to ask but forgot to mention?

Comment:  Dear Michael: yes, as shown by Torsten's and Ben's fine answers.

Answer (score 8):

In the category of finite dimensional manifolds, I proved this in a very long [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.1473v3) (p. 23): the composition of smooth fiber bundle maps is a smooth fiber bundle map. Spanier's counterexample is not a finite dimensional manifold.

Comment: Assuming that the composition is trivial what can be said about triviality of each bundle?

Answer (score 7):

I think that the following works: Let $X\to Y$ and $Y\to Z$ be locally trivial
fibrations with all spaces paracompact and $Z$ locally contractible (I do not assume that a
fibration implies that all fibres are homeo- or diffeomorphic). We want to show
that $X\to Z$ is locally trivial. We may then reduce to the case when $Z$ is
contractible and $Y=Z\times F$. Under the paracompactness assumption locally trivial
fibrations are homotopy invariant (see for instance Husemoller: Fibre bundles
GTM 20, Springer, Thm 9.8 plus a simple reduction to the principal bundle
case).  Hence there is a locally trivial fibre bundle $X'\to F$ such that $X\to Y$ is
isomorphic to $Z\times X'$ which is the local trivialtity.

Comment: Dear Torsten, does your parenthetical remark "(I do not assume...)" just mean that fibers depend on the connected component of the basis? 
And do you mean Thm 9.8 of Chapter 4 ?

Comment: Dear Georges, yes to both questions.